# deploy django on tomcat

Tags: django, tomcat, jython-2.7

I am using Django 1.8 on Jython in Windows 10. Have created a simple Django project following the tutorial https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01. After packaging using buildwar(including jars), when I deploy the mysite.war archive in tomcat, I get an error.
My project name is **mysite**, I have referenced the Jython path in web.xml. 
My project structure is

```
-mysite
 -WEB-INF
  -lib
   -jruby-extras-fileservlet.jar
   -jython.jar
  -lib-python
   -django
   -doj
   -polls
   -application_settingspy.class
   -application_settings.py
   -eggs.pth
  -web.xml
 -wsgi
```

Error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\jython27\Lib\modjy\modjy.py", line 80, in service
    self.exc_handler.handle(req, resp, wsgi_environ, mx, (typ, value, tb) )
  File "D:\jython27\Lib\modjy\modjy.py", line 76, in service
    self.dispatch_to_application(req, resp, wsgi_environ)
  File "D:\jython27\Lib\modjy\modjy.py", line 92, in dispatch_to_application
    app_callable = self.get_app_object(req, environ)
  File "D:\jython27\Lib\modjy\modjy_publish.py", line 68, in get_app_object
    return self.get_app_object_old_style(req, environ)
  File "D:\jython27\Lib\modjy\modjy_publish.py", line 120, in        get_app_object_old_style
    return self.load_object(source_filename, callable_name)
  File "D:\jython27\Lib\modjy\modjy_publish.py", line 142, in load_object
    self.raise_exc(NoCallable, "Error loading jython callable '%s': %s" %  (callable_name, str(x)) )
  File "D:\jython27\Lib\modjy\modjy.py", line 121, in raise_exc
    raise exc_class(message)
modjy.modjy_exceptions.NoCallable: Error loading jython callable 'application': No module named mysite
```

The application_settings file shows:

```
from mysite.settings import *
CONTEXT_ROOT = "mysite"
```

Comment: Having the same issue. Have you found any solution? @arnap

Comment: @HarikrishnanK.N. you may want to upvote questions when you have an interest for them: it will increase the odds of attracting an answer.